# Anchor is shifted on Galaxy s10 when app is not in full screen mode (Sceneform)

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I'm using ArSceneView to show anchors on a live camera feed. I'm using Anchor nodes to render the anchor on the camera feed.

When I'm testing my app, which by default is not in a full-screen mode, on galaxy s10, I see the anchor is not in the correct position. in fact, the shift is exactly the size of the black stripe on top of the screen. when I switch the app configuration to work on full screen ( in the device properties), and the camera feed is actually shown on the entire screen, the anchor is in the right position.
Anyone know how I can fix that or what the problem might be?